# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to integrate editorjs (https://editorjs.io/) in my project then I downloaded the editor.js to my project and loaded it in my html page:

```
    <script src='lib/editor.js'></script>
```

And I added:

```
    <script src='lib/myeditorloader.js'></script>
```

Which contains:

```
    import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';
    const editor = new EditorJS('editorjs');
```

I got that error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I added `type='module'` to get  and as thing are never simple with js, I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@editorjs/editorjs". 
Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I tried `import EditorJS from './editor.js';` but now I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './editor.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Is editojs buggy or what ?

Comment: Can you please remove your opinion about JS from the question

Comment: As you want to include the JS in your html directly you can use CDN `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest"></script>` 
instead of making it difficult using node modules for html directly which will require bundler, parser, babel, lot more

Comment: I don't know anything about NodeJS, in their "getting started", they give 3 way to install, composer, CDN and Manual, I chose the third, and they say to download the js and use that way, where's my mistake ?

Comment: @Andreas I removed my opinion about JS ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## Update~

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@editorjs/editorjs".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

First, install editorjs using command

```
 npm i @editorjs/editorjs --save
```

Then import it like

```
 import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs'
```

---

## Original Answer~

Don't use import while using `<script src='lib/editor.js'></script>`

#### Before

```
    import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';
    const editor = new EditorJS('editorjs');
```

#### After

```
    const editor = new EditorJS('editorjs');
```

Everything will be fine then!

Comment: Hello, I had the same issue and with your answer worked great! But how I would add the tools? If I state that I want to add a Header, it will return an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Header is not defined